# Having issues running a simple function upon clicking on a hyperlink using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use querySelectorAll to pickup all my href tags with classname "individual_email_click". Whenever someone clicks on any of the hyperlink with this classname thereafter, I want to run a function call "open_email". The below code is however not working. Anyone can help please? Thank you.

This is the relevant javascript.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
  document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', () => {submit_email();load_mailbox('sent'); event.preventDefault()});

  document.querySelectorAll('.individual_email_click').forEach(a =>{
    a.onclick = open_email;
  });
  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
});

function open_email() {
  console.log("this works!!!");
};
```

This is the relevant HTML script.

```
{% extends "mail/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>{{ request.user.email }}</h2>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="inbox">Inbox</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="sent">Sent</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="archived">Archived</button>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
    <hr>

    <div id="emails-view">
    </div>

    <div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking the function when you are assigning it to onclick, change it to this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.individual_email_click').forEach(a =>{
  a.onclick = open_email;
});

function open_email() {
  console.log("this works!!!");
};
```

```html
<a class="individual_email_click">click me!</a><br>
<a class="individual_email_click">or me!</a>
```

For your specific example you will need to run this logic after generating the links, you could do something like this:

```js
function create_table(emails) {

  console.log("hello");

  let table = document.createElement('table');
  let thead = document.createElement('thead');
  let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  table.appendChild(thead);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  document.querySelector("#emails-view").appendChild(table);
  console.log("hello there")

  let first_row = document.createElement('tr');
  let first_row_heading_1 = document.createElement('th');
  first_row_heading_1.innerHTML = "S/N";
  let first_row_heading_2 = document.createElement('th');
  first_row_heading_2.innerHTML = "Subject";
  let first_row_heading_3 = document.createElement('th');
  first_row_heading_3.innerHTML = "Sender";
  let first_row_heading_4 = document.createElement('th');
  first_row_heading_4.innerHTML = "Timestamp";
  first_row.appendChild(first_row_heading_1);
  first_row.appendChild(first_row_heading_2);
  first_row.appendChild(first_row_heading_3);
  first_row.appendChild(first_row_heading_4);
  thead.appendChild(first_row);

  let counter = 1;
  for (var key in emails) {

    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    let row_data_1 = document.createElement('td');
    row_data_1.innerHTML = counter;

    let row_data_2 = document.createElement('td');
    let row_data_2_a = document.createElement('a');
    row_data_2_a.innerHTML = emails[key]['subject'];
    row_data_2_a.href = "#0";
    row_data_2_a.className = "individual_email_click";
    row_data_2.appendChild(row_data_2_a);

    let row_data_3 = document.createElement('td');
    row_data_3.innerHTML = emails[key]['sender'];

    let row_data_4 = document.createElement('td');
    row_data_4.innerHTML = emails[key]['timestamp'];

    row.appendChild(row_data_1);
    row.appendChild(row_data_2);
    row.appendChild(row_data_3);
    row.appendChild(row_data_4);
    tbody.appendChild(row);

    counter ++;
  };

  document.querySelector("table").border = "1px solid";
  document.querySelector("table").style.width = "100%";
  
  // add this here instead
  document.querySelectorAll('.individual_email_click').forEach(a =>.  {
    a.onclick = open_email;
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi. I amended the code but the function open_email is still not running though.

Comment: @Shaun just added an working example above, where are you placing your JS code in the html document?

Comment: Hi @Asleepace, the JS code is on a separate file 'mail/inbox.js'. I have re-attached the full code above for your reference. Apologies if it looks very messy!

Comment: @Shaun could be wrong, but it looks like your `create_table` function doesn't print anything to the screen after the for loop no?

Comment: @Shaun wait I see the issue, you are adding the `open_email` to onclick before `create_table` is even called. Since that also appear to be async, you will need to add the onclick function after they are generated (or during).

Comment: @Shaun just updated the answer, lemme know if that works

Comment: It works now!!! But I still don't understand what is the issue. What I did to solve the problem was transfer the chunk of javascript " ... a.onclick = open_email" to under my create_table function

Comment: @Shaun nice yeah the issue was the links hadn’t been created on the page yet, which meant querying their selector returned nothing. Order of operations essentially.

Comment: This is really helpful! I been working on this the entire morning without any meaningful outcome and you solved it just by looking at it. Really amazing! Thanks a lot for your help and see you around!

Comment: @Shaun glad to help, sticking with a problem all day and finally getting it to work is what programming is about haha, see you around!